# How to input numbers into a cell of a table?

Tags: java

So far I wrote code that makes a table looking kind of like the table from excel and I am able to input letters words when it compiles, but I cant say for example 1a equals 5 and make the cell in 1a show 5 inside it.this is what my table looks like so far. This is my code to draw up the table:

```
package table;

public class Spreadsheat {

    private int xVal = 137;
    private int yVal = 1;
    private int[][] table = new int [20][20];
    private char yaxis = 'A';
    private int xaxis = 0;


    public Spreadsheat(){
        for(int i = 0; i < xVal; i++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(" |");
        for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++){
            System.out.print("| " + yaxis + "\t" + "|" );
            yaxis = (char) (yaxis + 1);
        }

        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < xVal; i++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }

        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j <10;j++){
            System.out.print(" " + xaxis + "|");
            for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++){
                System.out.print("|" + "\t" + "|" );
            }

            System.out.println();
            xaxis = xaxis + 1;
        }
    }
    public void setxval(int xVal) {
        this.xVal = xVal;
    }
    public int getxVal() {
        return xVal;
    }
    public void setyVal(int yVal) {
        this.yVal = yVal;
    }
    public int getyVal() {
        return yVal;
    }
    public void setTable(int table[][]) {
        this.table = table;
    }
    public int[][] gettable() {
        return table;
    }
}
```

And this is my client program:

```
package Client;

import java.util.Scanner;

import table.Spreadsheat;

public class VisiCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        Spreadsheat table = new Spreadsheat();
        boolean end = false;
        while(end == false){
            String input = kb.next();
            System.out.println(input);
            if(input.contains("quit")){
                end = true;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Random comment: Spreadsheet, with `ee` not `ea`...

Answer (score 2):

- Your Spreadsheet needs a way to update `table`.  For example, you need a method like this in your Spreadsheet class:

```
public void setValue(int row, int col, int value) {
    if (row >= 0 && row < 20 && col >=0 && col < 20) {
        table[row][col] = value;
    }
}
```

- You need a method way to convert your keyboard input so you can call `table.setValue(...)`.  For example, if you enter "2A=8", your method should parse that string into x=1, y=0, v=8 and call table.setValue(x,y,v).  It's up to you if you want the method in Spreadsheet or in your client.
- You need a method in Spreadsheet so you can print out your table to the screen with the updated content.  You will realize you need to format your content so that your columns line up properly.  The easiest way is to set each column to a fixed width say 8 and use `java.text.DecimalFormat` to convert your int to String.

I guess this is a start.